# `eb swap AAAA --destination_name BBBB --profile CCCC` returns ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Environment 'AAAA' is pending deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

Hello I am implementing Blue-Green Deployment with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and it seems the deployment has been completed successfully. but I can not swap blue/green using ebcli.

Following command returns an error.

```
eb swap AAAA --destination_name BBBB --profile CCCC
```

the error message is as follows

```
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Environment 'AAAA' is pending deployment.  Wait until the environment is available and try again.
```

**Additional Infomation**

eb --version: EB CLI 3.20.2 (Python 3.8.0)
I can swap on AWS Management Console.

is there anyone who had the same error?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved.

I just implement the swap command after waiting until the deployment complete, it worked.